# Rock, Paper, Scissors. Problem to tie. (python)

Tags: python, user-input

I followed a guide to make a rock paper scissors game. It was all going smoothly but the tutorial didn't include a way to tie the game. I thought I could do this myself but the code i wrote isn't working. I am very new to coding so I can't realise what I did wrong.

I thought this code would work but instead it's just print the text for when the player loses against the computer. Here is the code.

```
import random

uw = 0
cpw = 0

options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]

while True:
    uinput = input("Type Rock/Paper/Scissors or Q to quit: ").lower()
    if uinput == "q":
        break

    if uinput not in options:
        continue

    rn = random.randint(0, 2)
    #rock: 0, paper: 1, scissors: 2
    cpp = options[rn]
    print("Computer picked", cpp + ".")

    if uinput == "rock" and cpp == "scissors":
        print("You won!")
        uw += 1

    elif uinput == "paper" and cpp == "rock":
        print("You won!")`
        uw += 1

    elif uinput == "scissors" and cpp == "paper":
        print("You won!")
        uw += 1
    elif uinput "paper" and cpp == "paper":
        print("It's a tie, no points.")
    
    elif uinput "rock" and cpp == "rock":
        print("It's a tie, no points.")
    
    elif uinput "scissors" and cpp == "scissors":
        print("It's a tie, no points.")
    
    else:
        print("You lost!")
        cpw += 1


print("You won", uw, "times.")
print("The computer won", cpw, "times")
print("Goodbye")
```

Comment: As a side comment, you could just check `if uinput == cpp` instead of checking the three individual cases.

Comment: `elif uinput "paper" and cpp == "paper":` This is a syntax error, because you forgot the `==` after `uinput`.  This code will not run at all.  Are you sure this is your real code?

Comment: just a suggestion, you could simplify the computer picking part with a simple random.choice() function. ie cpp = random.choice(options)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your game isn't accurately who won or lose or tie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not comparing your tie rows to the string:

```py
    elif uinput "paper" and cpp == "paper":
        print("It's a tie, no points.")
```

Should be:

```py
elif uinput == "paper" and cpp == "paper":
    print("It's a tie, no points.")
```

Here the `==` is missing from your code and that's what is checking that your
`uinput` is the same as "paper"

But, instead of repeating these `elif` statements with `and` for each of the options, the DRY (do not repeat yourself)
best-practice of coding would insist you use:

```py
elif uinput == cpp:
    print("It's a tie, no points.")
```

This compares uinput to the computer's selection directly so it doesn't matter *which* choice you both made, if they are the same, it's a tie.